# Passing a dbset as a parameter to a function

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity

I couldn't quite find the answer I was looking for searching through stack so Im posting this.

Given this context

```
  public ProjectionsContext()
        : base("name=ProjectionsDatabase")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Projection> Projections { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Symbol> Symbols { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<TradePriceData> TradePriceDatas { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        **//set all decimal properties in Projection Entity to be Required
        var decimalproperties = typeof(Projection).GetProperties()
                                  .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal));
        foreach (var property in decimalproperties)
        {
            var lambda = CreateLambdaExpression<Projection, decimal>(property);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Projection>()
                .Property(lambda)
                .IsRequired();
        }**

        //add the custom configurations for each entity
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    }
}
```

I want to refactor out the bolded code, which obviously isn't that difficult but I can't seem to figure out how to pass in an Entity (Projection in the example above) so I can pass in any entity to set the properties.

Something like;

```
private static void SetEntityPropertiesRequired<TEntity>(
                        DbModelBuilder modelBuilder,
                        TEntity entity)
    {
        //set all decimal properties in Projection Entity to be Required
        var decimalproperties = typeof (entity).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof (decimal));

        foreach (var property in decimalproperties)
        {
            var lambda = BuildLambda<entity, decimal>(property);
            modelBuilder.Entity<entity>()
                .Property(lambda)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

and calling it like so;

```
 SetEntityPropertiesRequired<Projection>(modelBuilder);
```

yields an error, method requires two parameters.

**Update:**

The answer, per SLaks answer in total is;

```
  private static void SetEntityPropertiesDecimalTypeToRequired<TEntity>(
                        DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) where TEntity : class
    {
        //set all decimal properties in Projection Entity to be Required
        var decimalproperties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal));

        foreach (var property in decimalproperties)
        {
            var lambda = BuildLambda<TEntity, decimal>(property);
            modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>()
                .Property(lambda)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

Called like this;

```
SetEntityPropertiesDecimalTypeToRequired<Projection>(modelBuilder);
```

A nice bonus would being able to pass in the property type(decimal, int, string, etc)! Anyone want to give that a try since all types arent the same, some are structs and some are classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a generic method:

```
private static void SetEntityPropertiesRequired<TEntity>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //set all decimal properties in Projection Entity to be Required
    var decimalproperties = typeof (TEntity).GetProperties()
    ...
```

Comment: I tried that but <TEntity> is always grayed out and the parameter type Entity is red. Ok the parameter has to be TEntity entity and now it works, ty

Comment: I jumped the gun,   decimalproperties = typeof (entity).GetProperties() ; entity is in red as it is everywhere in the method. When I call the method how is Projection passed? ie; SetEntity....(modelBuilder, <Projection>), it doesnt like the entity passed that way obviously, how is it passed?

Comment: `typeof(TEntity)`, and `SetEntity<Projection>(modelBuilder)`

Comment: I understand what your saying but that doesnt make sense to me. Im not an expert in this so please enlighten me. See my updated post as passing entity, entity in the updated code is always red and the method call isnt liked either

Comment: You want a type parameter, not an argument.  I fixed my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67876/discussion-between-dinotom-and-slaks).